# .mobileconfig profile creation for IKEv2 VPN connection

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I've created a `.mobileconfig` profile using Apple Configurator 2 to set up a IKEv2 VPN profile on macOS and iOS devices. (*I need to use the configurator since it allows to set all the required settings for my connection, such as encryption level. You can't set the same settings via VPN Settings on Mac*).

When adding this profile to macOS (Catalina 10.15.6), it asks for username and password for the authentication (which is normal procedure). If I enter the login details incorrectly at this stage, I will see "User authentication failed" while trying to connect to the VPN. Then I change the password to the correct one in `Network > my VPN connection > Authentication Settings`.

**Issue:** even though I change password to the correct one and click **Apply**, it still shows "User authentication failed" and only profile recreation helps. So basically, in some way the stored credentials get corrupted on any change of credentials in Network profiles manager.

Could someone suggest what is the solution here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Why do you enter the wrong login credentials only to correct them later? What happens if you enter the right credentials to begin with?

Comment: Hi @jaume! If I enter the correct creds - everything works works fine and I'm able to connect. 

But, following my initial message, if I enter the credentials correctly while installing the profile, then for the sake of a test, change the password to incorrect in Settings, and then again will correct it to a right one - I won't be able to connect. As it seems like the password gets corrupted instantly on any change.